# Databricks Stream Data Suddenly Stops Streaming after successfully saving results to delta table

Tags: pyspark, databricks

The following code to Upsert from streaming queries using foreachBatch successfully streams data to delta table and then suddenly stops streaming and returns the message:

Stream stopped...
Out[212]: <pyspark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery at 0x7fca80c164f0>

The code that is run is as follows:

```
from delta.tables import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/data/aggregates")

# Function to upsert microBatchOutputDF into Delta table using merge
def upsertToDelta(microBatchOutputDF, batchId):
  (deltaTable.alias("t").merge(
      microBatchOutputDF.alias("s"),
      "s.key = t.key")
    .whenMatchedUpdateAll()
    .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
    .execute()
  )

# Write the output of a streaming aggregation query into Delta table
(streamingAggregatesDF.writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .foreachBatch(upsertToDelta)
  .outputMode("update")
  .option("checkpointLocation", f"{location}/_checkpoints")
  .start()
)
```

Second part of this question (which I think is connected) is when I run the code a second time I get a new error:

```
py4j.Py4JException: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4743.execute.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and attempted to modify the same
target row in the Delta table in possibly conflicting ways. By SQL semantics of Merge,
when multiple source rows match on the same target row, the result may be ambiguous
as it is unclear which source row should be used to update or delete the matching
target row. You can preprocess the source table to eliminate the possibility of
multiple matches.
```

Can you let me know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Not sure which part of error message is not clear? It's pretty black and white. `Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and attempted to modify the same
target row in the Delta table in possibly conflicting way`. Before merging, join the dataframe on `s.key = t.key`, to find the offending rows. If they're not supposed to be in source of target, remove them. If they're expected to be in source, then find a way to deduplicate before merging.